# Pure sine wave 500 W inverter

Tags: arduino, inverter, mosfet-driver, proteus, sine

[image]

[image]

I am trying to come up with a pure sine wave DC to AC inverter. Above is the circuit diagram I tried simulating in Proteus 8086.

I got errors as shown above, please help me fix those errors. See where the circuit is wrong and help me make correction.

Comment: Which is node #00005?

Comment: Don't know if it's what is causing the SPICE sim to fail, but you've got the VS pins of the two gate drive ICs crossed over - the VS pin should go to the same half-bridge as the gates it is driving.

Comment: C1 and C2 have wrong values.

Comment: Kindly tell me how to get the right values

Comment: You can't use 10k series gate resistors for PWM. About 10-50 ohms would be correct. Check the data sheet for the gate drivers for proper boost capacitor values (something like 100 nF to 2 uF). For timestep too small, maybe add some ESR to capacitors.

Comment: You also need to invert the signals to Lin so the low side is OFF while high side is ON.